# fs.trash.root not working. Have I configured it wrongly?

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to evaluate the hadoop trash option. I used this property in core-site.xml

```
<property>
 <name>fs.trash.root</name>
 <value>hdfs://Machinename:8020/Trash</value>
</property>
```

before using this I tried with

```
<property>
 <name>fs.trash.root</name>
 <value>/Trash</value>
</property>
```

But under both these cases the Trash directory is created under /user/username/  username is hbase.

What I get : hdfs://Machinename:8020/user/hbase/.Trash

But what I want is,

hdfs://Machinename:8020/Trash

and I hope thats what I have configured for. Have I missed something? Please let me know..

Thanks,

V.Sriram

Comment: What version of Hadoop are you running?

Comment: Hadoop 20.0 is the version I am using

Answer (score 1):

[Trash API documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/Trash.html) says that trashes in 0.20 are created per user, so It's impossible to do as you desired.
["How to correctly configure trash directory in Hadoop-0.20" question](http://getsatisfaction.com/cloudera/topics/how_to_correctly_configure_trash_directory_in_hadoop_0_20) on getsatisfaction.com

Comment: Oh thanks for your quick reply :-). I too saw that they have even removed that property from core-default.xml. But I am not sure why would they do this as it would prevent us in creating our own trash directory.